# How to use surf browser

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser

I stumbled upon the [surf browser](http://surf.suckless.org/) which is light weight. But i could not find the shortcut keys for the same (Going back, open multiple tabs if possible).

I could not find shortcuts page in the official site. Do you know the shortcuts for surf browser?

Comment: tab support is ok, its not needed. But do you know shortcut keys? I could not find in official site.

Comment: You can have tabbed surf! :D Same website you got surfed from, go to the tools/ button and click on tabbed. Download and build/install it, and then you can run tabbed instead of surf. `man tabbed` for hotkeys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surf is basically a standalone web view with a *very* limited feature set, and as such has no tab support. From the [web page you linked](http://surf.suckless.org/):

> I'd never thought I'd enjoy using a browser with no tab support until I forced myself to use surf for a week.

Everything else is listed in its `man` page, with is part of the download and installed with the browser. `man surf` will help if you installed it properly. You can also open the almost plain-text file `surf.1` instead.

`Ctrl-H` goes back, `Ctrl-L` forward. There are additional shortcuts for incremental searching, scrolling, printing, reloading and a handful of other things, but that's it. Notably absent, of course, are shortcuts for handling multiple tabs.

Comment: It's 800 lines of code, what can be expected?

Comment: Note that the "very limited feature set" is a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy to get tab support in `surf` with `tabbed`. Just install `tabbed` (>= v0.4) and run `tabbed surf -e`. The keys are documented on `man tabbed`, here they are in brief:

- `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to open a new tab
- `Ctrl-Shift-j` / `Ctrl-Shift-l` to go to the previous / next tab
- `Ctrl-[0..9]` to go to the nth tab
- `Ctrl-Tab` to toggle between two most recent tabs (like `Alt-Tab`)
- `Ctrl-q` to close tab.